# Expressão regular para substituir conteúdo do atributo src da tag <img> do html

Tags: delphi, regex

Olá,

Não entendo quase nada de expressão regular, portanto, queria que vocês me ajudassem com uma expressão para substituir apenas o que tiver entre as aspas duplas no atributo src da tag  do html, ou seja, o conteúdo deste atributo algo assim:

```
TRegEx.Replace(Str, '(?<=<img\s+[^>]*?src=(?<q>[""]))(?<url>.+?)(?=\k<q>)', 'Nova string');
```

Tinha pego essa expresão de uma questão falando sobre esse mesmo tema em C#, mas no Delphi não está funcionando.

Aguardo ansciosamente por qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que a expressão que você busca é:

```
\<img(.|\n|\r)+src="[^"]*$1"(.|\r.|\n)+\>
```

Onde:

- `\<img` é auto-explanatório;
- `(.|\n|\r)` significa qualquer caractere. O ponto significa qualquer caractere que não seja quebra de linha. Os dois outros caracteres são quebras de linha. O caractere pipe (`|`) é o operador lógico "ou";
- O sinal de mais significa o que estiver à esquerda, ao menos uma vez, mas até infinitas vezes;
- `[^"]*` sifnifica qualquer coisa diferente de aspas, de zero a infinitas vezes;
- `$1` é uma forma de identificar o que você quer encontrar. Estou enferrujado com Delphi, então se alguém souber a forma certa e não for esta, por favor edite minha resposta :)

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda e explicações, mas não funcionou :-(

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu estava vendo isso vai depender da [biblioteca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282749/best-delphi-regex-library) de REGEX que você esta usando

Supondo que esteja usando a [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/)

#### REGEX

```
pattern : (<img.*src=")([^"]*)(".*>)
replace : $1"URL ALTERAÇÃO"$3
```

[Veja no regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pA8iG3/1)

#### OBS

- "URL ALTERAÇÃO" é sua string para substituir o grupo 2 que é a url atual

A regex `(?<=<img.*src=")([^"]*)(?=".*>)` não pode ser usado pois o *look behind* `(?<=)` não permite quantificador um sua composição como o `*`.